# Does Incremental Linking really reduce the size of an image?

Tags: linker

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf.aspx) an image is larger with "incremental linked" than without:

> An incrementally linked program is functionally equivalent to a program that is nonincrementally linked. However, because it is prepared for subsequent incremental links, an incrementally linked executable (.exe) file or dynamic-link library (DLL) is larger than a nonincrementally linked program ...

I made a few tests in release mode (just to test the impact of this feature) and I don't see differences in the size of the image produced. How to explain this? Is the MSDN information wrong? Has anyone tried this and seen which impact this linking feature has on the (released) image file.

Answer (score 0):

The quote you supplied says an incrementally linked program is **larger**, not smaller.

The size increases because not all of the executable is relinked every time, so some old code remains in the executable and is just no longer used. The next full (non-incremental) build will remove the no longer used code. You should always do a full build (non-incremental) before actual release to remove the extraneous noise (and reduce your executable size).

There's no way to tell know in advance what the size difference will be specifically, because it depends on the exact code in your application, what you change, how many times you change it, choices the linker makes about whether it can just do that change incrementally or not, how long it's been since the last full build, and a lot of other variable information.

Comment: Thanks, larger. But the size is NOT affected, even with full build.

Comment: My goal is to find out how many percent the delta of size would be